# Texstudio editor setup on Mac

Tags: texstudio, mac

Installed Texstudio on my new MacBook and faced a problem: in the editor the size of the tab is two spaces. Do you know how to change this value to four spaces? Haven't found this in editor settings.

Comment: Welcome :) // Did you check "Preferences"? http://transit.iut2.upmf-grenoble.fr/doc/texstudio/html/usermanual_en.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in Advanced Editor Settings

[image]

Comment: Looks like I don't have such tab in my settings(. Which version of texstudio are you using? Or is it some plugin or smth?

Comment: Oh I see, there is a button "Show advanced options" at the very bottom. Thanks a lot!